# Why when using super().__init__ I can only initialize first parameter in parent class

Tags: python, initialization, parent-child

Don't understand why this works:

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name="Fish"):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__(self)

terry = Trout()

# Initialize first name
terry.first_name = "Terry"

# Use parent __init__() through super()
print(terry.first_name + " " + terry.last_name)

# Use child __init__() override
print(terry.water)
```

But if I would like every child class to have different last_name y can't delete its value and define it later like we did with first_name:

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__(self)

terry = Trout()

# Initialize first name
terry.first_name = "Terry"
terry.last_name =  "Crews"

# Use parent __init__() through super()
print(terry.first_name + " " + terry.last_name)

# Use child __init__() override
print(terry.water)
```

```
Error: TypeError: Fish.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'last_name'
```

Comment: Why are you even calling super? You are not initialising any arguments of the parent class since child class doesn't have the necessary information. Also you don't need to provide `self` when calling super. Because you did right now you have this mapping `super().__init__(first_name=self, last_name=None)` hence you are getting TypeError for last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the attributes in the constructor, you need to actually pass them as arguments; your child class needs to accept them as arguments so that it can pass them to the parent class.

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)

terry = Trout("Terry", "Crews")

print(terry.first_name + " " + terry.last_name)
print(terry.water)
```

If you don't plan to use the constructor to set the attributes, remove those parameters and just set the attributes to default values (e.g. `None`):

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = None
        self.last_name = None

class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__()

terry = Trout()
terry.first_name = "Terry"
terry.last_name = "Crews"

print(terry.first_name + " " + terry.last_name)
print(terry.water)
```

You can also provide defaults in the parent class that are overridden by defaults in the child class that can in turn by overridden by optional arguments, e.g.:

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, water, first_name, last_name="Fish"):
        self.water = water
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name="Trout"):
        super().__init__("freshwater", first_name, last_name)

terry = Trout("Terry", "Crews")

print(terry.first_name + " " + terry.last_name)
print(terry.water)
```

Comment: I understand now, thank you for taking the time to help a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

When using `super().__init__()` method, you need to precise the parameters you are inheriting. and even inside your Trout constructor you need to mention all its parameters including the ones its inheriting i.e `def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, water="freshwater")`. So your Trout class should look like the code below

```
class Trout(Fish):
  def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, water="freshwater"):
    self.water=water
    super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not initialising any arguments of the parent class since child class doesn't have the necessary information. Also you don't need to provide self when calling super.